# Bootstrap tables not displaying correctly in Jsfiddle React code

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

In my sample React app in Jsfiddle, Bootstrap tables are not displaying correctly. Yes, I have used className instead of class in JSX. Please suggest whats wrong in the code.

Link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/hgondela/teag0sqf/5/

```
var HelloTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (  
        <div> 
          <div className='jumbotron  text-center'>Bootstrap table in React JSX </div> 
            <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th> 
                <th>Age</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td> 
                <td>94</td>
              </tr>
            </table>    
      </div>
    )
  }    
})

ReactDOM.render(<HelloTable name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the elements in the jsfiddle with my browser and found that the browser automatically inserts a `<tbody>` element inside the table wrapping it that bootstrap uses for styles. So I added the `<tbody>`:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    // table stuff
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and now the table looks great: https://jsfiddle.net/teag0sqf/6/

Comment: It worked. Thanks.
But do you know why browser did not add <tbody> automatically in JSX code?